# Delete specific class in page (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i delete all classes "green" in the page using jQuery? I don't know what selector it has. `find('.green').removeClass('green')` does not work.

Comment: are $(".green") and $('*.green') identical by speed?

Comment: They are the same thing; both are terribly slow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(".green").removeClass("green");
```

Comment: Actually, 10 seconds. Ah the pain.

Comment: jon - do you get an early warning signal of a new jq question;)

Comment: @Redsquare I wish :) I just get lucky from time to time.

Comment: +1 Aaah beat me to it by 3 minutes. If none of you guys were online I would have got this! See -> $(".green").removeClass("green");

Comment: Quick, Karim79, Paolo, Redsquare and I better disperse before we cause a jQuery gravity-well on Stackoverflow!